# pgfplots discarding xtick coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I'm creating a several graphs with pgfplots.  The problem I'm coming across is that some graphs do not have a value for the last coordinate as per the example below (and I want to keep the ticks on the x axis consistent).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,5,10,20,50,100},xticklabels={1,2,5,10,20,50,100},unbounded coords=jump,xminorticks=false,yminorticks=false]
    \addplot[smooth] coordinates {
      (1.0000000000, 1.3562500000)
      (2.0000000000, 1.2825000000)
      (5.0000000000, NaN)
      (10.0000000000, 4.2087500000)
      (20.0000000000, 10.7962500000)
      (50.0000000000, 91.7450000000)
      (100.0000000000, NaN)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Is there a way to force the x axis to include the tick and label for 100? The 'unbounded coords=jump' option does not help since there are no more lines to draw.

Thanks

Comment: You can add something like `xmax=102` to the `axis` options.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer, but perhaps you would like to wait a little longer before accepting it to see if someone else gives a better solution.

Comment: You can also check the `enlarge limits` options in the manual.

Comment: Since you say you want the axes to be consistent between different plots, I would suggest going with Gonzalo's suggestion (and also supplying `xmin=0` explicitly).

Comment: Actually I tried Gonzalo's option (xmax=100) and 'enlargelimits=true'. This gives me a consistent output with similar spacing on both sides.  So far I like it.  Will go ahead and accept the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like `xmax=102` to the axis options.

Comment: I ended up using 'xmax=100,enlargelimits=true'. Works fine. Thanks.